# How to append build number to css <div> tag

Tags: maven

I am using GWT , maven build tool, and Hudson tool for continuous integration. I have got a requirement of displaying build number in one of the HTML/JSP file. Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have a look at this blog post I made, I think it can be a good starting point for what you want http://www.bloggure.info/work/getting-source-revision-for-a-deployed-app-using-maven-and-a-servlet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cedric has the point, good article.
It also depends from the environment and configuration, in my projects I usually do the following to simply get the Manifest contents:

```
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

And then

```
Properties properties = new Properties(); 
properties.load(is);
String buildNumber = properties.getProperty("BuildNumber");
```

or

```
Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
manifest.get...
```